# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied (with a select statement)

Tags: python, sql

I have discovered a problem with my system: (A user logins and they should with the help of this procedure recall previously created list linked to this account)

```
def ListV():
global AnswersDictionary, resultListItems1
db = sqlite3.connect("Users.db")
c = db.cursor()
User = AnswersDictionary["User"]

sql_SelectStatement = "Select [List Name], Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5, Item6, Item7, Item8  from Lists where User=(?)"

c.execute(sql_SelectStatement, User)
resultList = c.fetchall()

resultListItems1 = []
ListNames = []
for mediaList in resultList:
    resultListItems2 = []
    ListNames.append(mediaList[0])

    for listItem in mediaList:

        if listItem != None:
            resultListItems2.append(listItem)


    resultListItems1.append(resultListItems2)    



program.addLabel("title", "View Lists")
program.addLabelOptionBox("Options: ", ListNames)
program.addButtons(["Go", "Cancel",], CheckListV)
```

I get this error when trying to run this procedure: 
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 8 supplied.

I have found no help online or anywhere else on this issue. Most of the binding issues seem to be insert statements.

Comment: What is AnswersDictionary? Apparently, its "User" key is a list of eight elements.

Comment: Answers dictionary is a store of some other variables needed for the whole program. In this procedure only user is needed. There should only be one user.

Comment: But you need to show what User is. As I say, apparently it is a list of eight values.